# R convert names to numbers

Tags: r, pearson, pvclust

I have a data frame with donations and names of donors.

```
**donation**              **Donor**
 25.00               Steve Smith
 20.00               Jack Johnson
 50.00               Mary Jackson
  ...                   ...
```

I'm trying to do some clustering using the `pvclust` package.  Unfortunately the package doesn't seem to take non-numerical data.

```
> rs1.pv1 <- parPvclust(cl, rs1, nboot=10)
Error in cor(x, method = "pearson", use = use.cor) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I have two questions.

1) Is there another package or method that would do this better?

2) Is there a way to "normalize" the donor names list?  Ie get a list of unique donor names, assign each an id number and then insert the id number into the data frame in place of the character name.

Comment: I strongly suspect you **don't** want to convert those names to numeric and feed them to `parPvclust`. Instead, from a quick look at `?parPvclust`, and the example in `?lung`, it looks like you should use the `Donor` column as the rownames attribute, and then remove it from the matrix or data.frame.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: make this an answer???

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what you're trying to do in this example?  e.g., are you trying to come up with clusters of donors with similar donation levels (in which case I would be tempted to use `ave` or `plyr::ddply` to get average donations per donor, *then* cluster them ...)

Comment: @BenBolker -- I don't have the time right now, plus it's probably worth waiting for a response from the OP.  I just wanted to amplify your and Iselzer's misgivings, before the OP went off and did something possibly nonsensical with that function!

Comment: There are a bunch of other columns to the data (donation event, purpose, fiscal year, etc).  I just looking for any unexpected relationships.  There's no real master plan.  Kind of like graphing data, you never know what you'll find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For number 2:

```
#If donor is a factor then

as.numeric(donor)

#will transform your factor to numeric.
#If it isn't, tranform it to a factor and the to numeric
as.numeric(as.factor(donor))
```

However, I'm not sure that transforming the donor list to a numeric and then using cor makes sense at all.

HTH

Comment: Beat you by 11 seconds.  Do you mean `as.numeric(as.factor(donor))` .. ?

Answer (score 2):

How about `rs1 <- transform(rs1, Donor=as.numeric(factor(Donor)))` ?  (*Warning*: I haven't thought about what you're doing enough to know whether that makes sense -- so I'm only answering question #2, not question #1).  Typically `Donor` would already be a factor (this is what e.g. `read.table` or `read.csv` would do by default), so the `factor()` part would be redundant.